# Boot issue Ubuntu LiveUSB 16.04.3

Tags: boot, live-usb

I am a brand new user of the Linux-based OS and I would really like to learn it, except I can't even get in the damn thing!!

I have created a LiveUSB using Rufus as per the instructions on the Ubuntu site.  I am using Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS.

I have a modern ASUS motherboard with a Z170 chipset, so no issues booting from any USB device.

My USB flash drive is a 16GB Kingston Data Traveller G4 USB 3.0.  I also have an nVidia GeForce 970 GTX graphics card jnside my computer and outputting via DVI, if this has any relevance to my problem.

In Rufus, I selected the MBR option for use with UEFI and a FAT32 filesystem.

When I boot the USB device I get the menu to Try Ubuntu etc, with NO scrambled text like what many people have had.  But when I select Try or Install Ubuntu, I get a black screen with lots of garbled characters and nothing happens.  I've tried lots of different Linux-based USB and CD formats, but I always get this far and that's it.  It really is frustrating as I want to try and move away from Windows and learn something new.

Could this be a graphics card problem do you think?  I have also tried disabling Fast Boot and Secure Boot etc but no difference.

Comment: Have you tried booting with the `nomodeset` kernel parameter?

Comment: Thanks tnmo all for their suggestions, but I don't think the black screen many people have been getting is not the same as my problem.  I can't even try or Install Ubuntu.  Is there a way to change the graphics settings in Windows?  I don't know anything about Grub so would need some help with that  .  Thanks